# How to avoid undefined issue on table row

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to push the below table data into an array as shown below.
This works fine when they are all tds.
However if I have a th I get an undefined error.  How can I best handle this so if the row has a th use this else you td

```js
var test = document.querySelectorAll('.tableClass tr');
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    data.push({
        'x': document.querySelectorAll('.tableClass tr td:nth-child(2)')[0].innerText,
        'y': document.querySelectorAll('.tableClass tr td:nth-child(2)')[i].innerText,
        'z': i
    });
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

```html
    <table class="tableClass">
        <tr>
            <th>cat</th><th>dog</th><th>fish</th>
            <!--<td>cat</td><td>dog</td><td>fish</td>-->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>yes</td><td>no</td><td>no</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>yes</td><td>yes</td><td>no</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @anpsmn if you comment out the th items in the first line and uncomment to th in first  line.  You will see the desired  output.  Cant get ot working  with a mix of th and td?

Comment: when I tried that I got the following result data as [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1uzckybo/). Is that the expected output?

Comment: If the expected output is the same as the fiddle link I shared above then you can change `td:nth-chld(2)` to just `:nth-child(2)`

Comment: Didn't know you could use nth-child like that. This works  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to add the `th`'s to your DOM query, eg. `.tableClass tr th:nth-child(2)`. I would also suggest that you cache the elements in a variable instead of looking them up each time.

Here's what I came up with ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qp328av3/)):

```
var test = document.querySelectorAll('.tableClass tr');
var values = document.querySelectorAll('.tableClass tr td:nth-child(2), .tableClass tr th:nth-child(2)');
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    data.push({
        'x': values[0].innerText,
        'y': values[i].innerText,
        'z': i
     });
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```